# mysql left join and not equals should return only one row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, where-clause

Can some one please help me with the query for below requirement.

[image]

[image]

for above two tables i wrote below left join query

```
select distinct result 
from a 
    left join b on a.number = b.reference 
where a.color='red' and b.value != '10'
```

this query is returning both 1 and 2 as output.

but i am expecting only 2 as the output since list1 in table b have value:10 so query should not return row if value in list matches.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set-quantifier_, and works on the whole selected row. Skip those extra brackets and simply write `select distinct result from ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Your query is behaving exactly as specified because it is matching the 'red/list1' row in table a to all the 'list1' rows in table b (except the one that has value 10!) and likewise the 'red/list2' row will match to all the 'list2' rows in table b. So both the 'red' rows in table a will have multiple matches in table b and when you apply DISTINCT to the result set, you get both 1 and 2 returned.  If you try your query with SELECT * instead of SELECT DISTINCT RESULT, it should be clear what is happening.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this with a `left join`.  But the filtering condition is mostly in the `on` clause:

```
select a.result 
from a left join
     b
     on a.number = b.reference and b.value = '10'
where a.color='red' and b.reference is null;
```

Comment: thanks. this works best for me, since i have existing join query i can't use in queries

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want "red" rows in `a` for which there is no match in `b` with `value` `10`. I think this is better phrased with `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from tablea a 
where a.color = 'red' not exists (
    select 1
    from tableb b
    where b.reference = a.number and b.value = 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(result) from a where color='red' and
number not in (select reference from b where value =10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select result 
from a 
    left join b on a.number = b.reference AND b.value = 10
where a.color='red' and b.reference IS NULL
```